# Dev-C++ will not use resource file

Tags: c, dialog, win32gui

I've been trying for at least four hours now to launch a Win32 dialog that is stored in a resource file, to no avail. For the first hour, I tried to load a menu as a test; that did not work. The menu was not rendered. Later, I tried to add a dialog to my resource file; I did this by clicking Project->Add To Project... and then selected my resource script.

The dialog won't show up.

If it may help, here is my resource script:

```
601 DIALOG DISCARDABLE 0, 0, 239, 66
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CATPION "About"
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "&OK", IDOK, 174, 18, 50, 14
    GROUPBOX        "About this program...", IDC_STATIC, 7, 7, 225, 52
    CTEXT           "TestText", IDC_STATIC, 
16, 18, 144, 33
END
```

And my dialog-invoking code:

```
DialogBox(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(601), hwnd, AboutDlgProc);
```

Comment: Do your build logs indicate that you actually compiled the resource?

Comment: M'kay, turns out there were a bunch of syntax errors in my resource, which wasn't being compiled.  Thank you

Comment: Excellent, I think you're still going to need the `WS_VISIBLE` attribute, or a call to `ShowWindow` to make the dialog visible.

Comment: Turns out that by changing the font in the dialog i've re-broken everything

Comment: ff you don't post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we can't help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Add WS_VISIBLE to the dialog style flags or call [ShowWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx) in your dialog handler.

Comment: Still no luck with WS_VISIBLE.